# Self initialize a backbone view

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I'm wondering if there is a simple way to self initialize a backbone view. It's probably best I show an example of what I'm looking to do.

Currently the default way to initialize a backbone view is as follows:

```
var BBview = Backbone.View.extend({});
var myView = new BBview();
```

For name-spacing reasons I'd like to "auto" or "self" initialize the backbone view. For example.

```
var MyApp.MyView = Backbone.View.extend({}).initialize();
```

This way MyApp.MyView will automatically become my view instead of having to first create a variable to be the backbone view and then also create another variable to initialize it. Hopefully this makes sense. Any help is much appreciated. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Backbone.View.extend()` returns a constructor function so you can call `new` on it. The only tricky part is getting the precedence correct so that `extend` sees the arguments in its parentheses rather than `new` seeing them as arguments to the constructor:

```
var v = new (Backbone.View.extend({ ... }));
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/TpmtH/

Without the extra set of parentheses:

```
var v = new Backbone.View.extend({ ... });
```

you'll be doing (more or less) this:

```
var V = Backbone.View.extend;
var v = new V({ ... });
```

and that's not what you want.

I wouldn't recommend this sort of thing, you'll just confuse and puzzle whoever ends up looking at your code in six months. You're better off using a function to avoid namespace pollution:

```
var myView = (function() {
    var BBview = Backbone.View.extend({});
    return new BBview();
})();
```

That may not be as pretty or clever but it has the enormous advantage of being a common and instantly recognizable pattern.

Answer (score 1):

Just initialize the backbone view directly with the `new` operator:

```
var myView = new Backbone.View();
```

Or by using extend:

```
var myView = new (Backbone.View.extend({ 
      initialize : function() { console.log('init'); } 
}));
```